# Considerations for threading in web environment

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I am getting started with ASP.NET web development and was wondering what the differences are when multi-threading a standard winforms application versus a web-based application written in asp.net that will run in IIS. Is there any difference and if so, what are the limitations (and conversely any positives) of threading a web application,
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Windows GUI world, you always have the "UI thread" which you can use to communicate with the user. For example, you can start a `BackgroundWorker` in the UI thread, which will raise an event in the UI thread after completing its work: In a Windows UI application, you can be pretty sure that the UI thread is still there, unless the user has closed the application.

In the web world, you have no equivalent *main thread*. There are just web requests: Sometimes there are none and sometimes there are many at the same time; it is even possible that one single request will be handled by multiple threads without you knowing it. If you start a background thread with a lengthy operation, you need to either

- delay finishing the web request until the background thread has completed -- which means a slow response time for the user and somehow defeats the purpose of a background thread or
- regularly (during future requests) check the state of the thread and inform the user when it has finished.

Of course, that's only a problem if you want some user interaction after the thread has finished. If you don't, just start it and it will eventually finish (unless someone restarts IIS).

Answer (score 0):

Threading isn't really an issue in the web world. There isn't any state and each request is a new instance of the web page. There are ways to track state between requests such as cookies, sessionstate, viewstate.

Comment: This just isn't true. Plenty of web sites use threading on the server side.

Comment: @liam The question was in regards to ASP.NET and is 4 years old and is a valid answer for that period.